# form.submit fires multiple times, one extra time after each response

Tags: javascript, .net, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a form.submit that fires multiple times.  The first time, it's fine.  After I get the response back, if I click the submit button again, it fires twice.  Then thrice.  Seems like each time the response comes back, the submit fires an extra time the next time the button is clicked.

```
RetrievePassword = function () {
    var $popup = $("#fancybox-outer");
    var form = $popup.find("form");
    form.submit(function (e) {
        var data = form.serialize();
        var url = form.attr('action');
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            data: data,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {
                if (response.Success) {
                    $.fancybox.close();
                }

                alert(response.Message);
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                alert(xhr.statusText);
            }
        });

        e.cancelBubble = true;
        if (e.stopPropagation) e.stopPropagation();
        return false;
    });

};
```

I'm not even sure how to debug this.  Any advice is appreciated...

Comment: `e.cancelBubble = true; if (e.stopPropagation) e.stopPropagation(); return false;` is overkill. Since you are using jQuery doing `e.preventDefault();` is all you need (and `e.stopPropagation();` in case you need to prevent bubbling of the event - but usually that's not necessary)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are calling `RetrievePassword()` multiple times. Everytime you call it another `onsubmit` handler will be registered.

The solution is to register the handler only once.

Comment: You are right, I had the function calling from the input button as well: <input type="submit" value="Retrieve Password" onclick="javascript:RetrievePassword();" />